# rsyslog listen ip address

Tags: rsyslog

I am trying to configure rsyslog to listen on port 514 and want to make sure that it is only listening on 127.0.0.1.

It is accepting logs on 514 but it is listening on all ip address.

I have tried the following two configuration. with both cases it is listening on all interfaces.

```
$ModLoad imudp
$UDPServerRun 514
$UDPServerAddress 127.0.0.1
```

and

```
module(load="imudp")
input(type="imudp" port="514" Address="127.0.0.1")
```

rsyslog is not accepting the second configuration.

```
rsyslogd: the last error occured in /etc/rsyslog.conf, line 86:"input(type="imudp" port="514" Address="127.0.0.1")"
rsyslogd: the last error occured in /etc/rsyslog.conf, line 85:"module(load="imudp")
```

Here is the rsyslog version details.

> ## rsyslogd -v rsyslogd 5.8.10, compiled with:
>
> ```
>     FEATURE_REGEXP:                         Yes
>     FEATURE_LARGEFILE:                      No
>     GSSAPI Kerberos 5 support:              Yes
>     FEATURE_DEBUG (debug build, slow code): No
>     32bit Atomic operations supported:      Yes
>     64bit Atomic operations supported:      Yes
>     Runtime Instrumentation (slow code):    No
> ```

Comment: I think there actually is just a typo in `input(type="imudp" port="514" Address="127.0.0.1")` : address needs to be written with a lowercase A. Then it works for me.

Answer (score 7):

I think to bind to a particular address you do this (the difference with your initial config is that the Run HAS to come after the Address.

```
$ModLoad imudp
$UDPServerAddress 127.0.0.1 # BEFORE UDPSERVERRUN
$UDPServerRun 514
```